# Seeking Hotel Recommendations in Chiang Mai, Chiang Rai, and Pai with Indian Vegetarian Food Options

Tags: hotels, thailand, chiang-mai

We're a vegetarian family of five from India, and we're planning a trip to Chiang Mai, Chiang Rai, and Pai from December 5th to 15th. Could you recommend hotels in these locations that offer Indian vegetarian cuisine in their in-house restaurants? We value comfort and quality, and it's essential for us to have authentic vegetarian dining options.

Thank you for your assistance!

Warm regards,

Comment: Do they have to be hotels with vegetarian Indian food in their restaurants, or are you willing to go to Indian restaurants that are not part of hotels? Chiang Mai has a lot.

Comment: I've met Indians who live in Thailand in the most random places, but I've been quite disappointed the few times I've eaten at actual Indian restaurants, very different to in Malaysia. Most vegetarians and vegans eat at "เจ" restaurants. This is a dietary standard for Thai Buddhists that is stricter than vegetarian but not quite the same as vegan. They usually have yellow and red signs and often have the Chinese character 齋 for vegetarian as well as Thai เจ. To many people เจ looks like "17" in some common fonts. Most cities have one or more such restaurants.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question because given the constraints, it's quite specific and answerable -- although the answer is, sadly, "not possible".

Answer (score 4):

I would be very surprised if there are *any* hotels with in-house restaurants serving authentic vegetarian Indian food in Chiang Rai and particularly Pai, which are small provincial Thai towns with few if any Indian residents.  (Chiang Mai is much larger and might have options.)  Based on a cursory search, there is [exactly one Indian restaurant of any description in Pai](https://www.paicookingclass.com/bebe-spice-indian-restaurant), and it's run by a Thai lady as a side line for her Thai cooking classes.

Dare I suggest you widen your culinary horizons and explore Thai food?

Comment: There is also a samosa shop. But a difficulty with Thai food for someone who follows an Indian vegetarian diet (I am guessing no meat, possibly no eggs, but dairy allowed) is that a lot of Thai food contains fish in the sauces. Especially if they do not speak much Thai, they would probably have to eat at a vegan restaurant to be sure about many dishes.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Sure, walking into a random Thai restaurant won't work, but there are quite a few vegetarian places in all three.

Comment: Thai vegetarian food, actually Buddhist "เจ", pronounced "je" or "jae", doesn't use meat or any other animal ingredient like milk, eggs, or honey. It's distinct from vegan but should be compatible with Hindu vegetarianism I think. Might be worth a dedicated question. [Vegetarianism in Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_cuisine#Vegetarianism_in_Thailand)